# Who cut the crew's hair on Voyager, and where?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I wonder how does the crew take a haircut? Is there a beauty parlour in the Voyager? Like Kes, she has a stylish hairdo.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Suzan_Bagdadi

Comment: In Basics, Part II we see Harry cutting Janeway's hair...; https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpLfe.jpg

Comment: The Enterprise is to [Mot](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Mot) as Voyager is to...?

Comment: As much as I love Voyager, there is not one hairdo in it I'd like. So only glad to know which hairdressers to avoid.

Comment: Of all the things that normal people do in real life that are not shown on TV in general, hairdos are way down on the list of things I'd want to know about!

Comment: @Bent Not even Neelix’s?

Comment: @Bent: [For real?](http://thumbs.modthesims2.com/img/1/3/7/7/8/2/8/MTS_MistyBlue-880618-torres-6.jpg) Not even [this one](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/08/0f/0a/080f0a90a61b6319669fcbfacbb68db2.jpg)?

Comment: In real life, crewmen on ships and soldiers in the field often cut each other's hair.  Given that most of the people on Starfleet ships are smart and mechanically adept, why couldn't they simply learn to do it themselves - with some crewman (by way of talent or interest) becoming the one person every body else goes to for a haircut?  No need for "holo barbers" with the holodeck safety mechanisms turned off.  (That could give rise to a whole horror scenario - imagine a bug in the holobarber program that causes it to run wild with a straight razor in its hands.)

Answer (score 17):

### We don't know.

This has been the subject of speculation on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DaystromInstitute/comments/36r3r1/how_did_the_crew_of_voyager_get_haircuts/) and [other Star Trek forums](https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/who-cut-the-crews-hair.278567/page-2), but nobody's ever presented a solid answer from canon.

- One popular theory is that they used the holodeck and a holographic barber, with safety measures turned off so that the hologram's scissors could really cut their hair ... but the popularity of this idea is probably more due to its 'coolness' than to any actual canon evidence supporting it.
- [This forum poster claims](https://www.trekbbs.com/threads/who-cut-the-crews-hair.278567/page-2#post-11456119) that Janeway cut her own hair in the Star Trek novel *Captain's Table: Fire Ship*. But a perusal of [the book itself](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=fAReFEuvUOkC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=hair) suggests that the next poster is correct and she actually lost her bun in a fire rather than cutting it off herself.

Comment: Besides which, the Star Trek books aren't considered canon.

Comment: I would have assumed the doctor.

Comment: @Roddy What, none of them? I wasn't sure about that, but then the question became academic anyway since she didn't actually get a haircut in that book.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Only the movies and the TV seriees are officialy canon. But most of the books form their own coherent canon.

Answer (score 0):

"Computer, *BEEP* One pair of scissors *WRRRRRRRR*
*replicates scissors*
Jokes aside, Starfleet has quartermasters and presumably the members aboard are trained to handle thier own personal grooming. Since Voyager left without a FULL crew complement during it's mission in the badlands, they left without a host of various people, including counselor, etc, or a barber. But hair care shouldn't be a difficult task, women mostly wear their hair tied back.